# Distinguishability of Elements in a Combination

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 2 green chairs, 3 yellow chairs, and 4 blue chairs. In how many ways can we choose 3 chairs so **at least** one yellow chair is included?

I get this is a simple problem. You can simply do $9\choose{3}$ - $6\choose{3}$ (total # of ways - no yellow chairs).

Or you can go down the route of calculating all those combinations of 3 that include 1 yellow, 2 yellow, or 3 yellow: $3\choose1$$6\choose2$ + $3\choose2$$6\choose1$ + $3\choose3$$7\choose0$.

Either way, you get 64. Now this may be a moot point, but these questions must assume that all of the chairs are distinguishable, correct? Otherwise if you consider the question: how many ways can you choose one yellow chair, the answer would just be 1 (not $3\choose1$, or $3\choose2$, or $3\choose3$ as illustrated in the second solution).

How are we supposed to know these items are distinguishable, especially in problems involving same colored balls in an urn kind of problems?

Comment: "moot point", not "mute point".

Comment: I would read the problem as if the chairs are indistinguishable, because we are simply told the total number per color and not told specifically otherwise. But more precisions would be welcomed in the problem statement

Comment: Yes, I would treat the chairs as indistinguishable, so that the question is asking for  the number of integer solutions to $g+y+b=3$ with $0\leq g\leq 2,1\leq y\leq 3$ and $0\leq b\leq 4.$

Comment: Got it, makes sense. Thanks both.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! As a side note, please use MathJax when posting questions. There's a MathJax reference embedded linked in the help for posting/formatting a question.